# Why the path is different between Python terminal in code editor vs after compiled into exe

Tags: python

So I have this simple code in `C:\Work\Python Scripts\dfr_monthly\myfile.py`

```
print(os.getcwd())
print(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

When I run this file from code editor (VSCode), the output in the python terminal is

```
(base) C:\Work>C:/Users/coco/Anaconda3/python.exe "c:/Work/Python Scripts/dfr_monthly/myfile.py"
C:\Work
c:\Work\Python Scripts\dfr_monthly
```

Then I compiled it into exe but when I run it the output is
[image]

Why is it different between the exe output vs python terminal in vscode? I'm kind of confused what's happening here

Comment: Err, because you are in a different working directory?

Comment: i run it exactly from the same directory tho.. the exe and the file located in the same directory

Comment: Executables are unpacked in Windows in a temp directory as you can see and from there the actual code is run from and then removed again. Try to add this to your code: `os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))` and then recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

Executables are unpacked in Windows in a temp directory as you can see and from there the actual code is run from and then removed again. Try to add this to your code, at the top:

```
os.chdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
```

Then recompile it.

This should change directory into the actual directory, where you run the code from.